# Carregar spinner dentro de outro

Tags: android

Queria saber como ao selecionar um item do spinner, outro spinner seja preenchido com um Adapter. Eu tentei dessa forma:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int posicao, long arg3) {

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 
           = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, minhalista);
}
```

Mas ele não deixa criar o Adapter, no meu caso só pode ser no clique pois vou puxar de um banco de dados, e carregar essa lista.
Como faço pra jogar a lista no spinner2, quando um item do spiner1 for selecionado?

Comment: Não deixa criar porquê? Tem algum erro? Qual?

Answer (score 3):

No seu código, você está passando o evento do callback como contexto. Passe sua Activity.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                           int posicao, long arg3) {

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 
           = new ArrayAdapter<String>([SUA ACTIVITY AQUI].this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, minhalista);
}
```